# Is it possible to control visibility of a div through anchor object with css?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I want to use a link pointing to a anchor in the same dokument to control the visibility of div's inside a dokument. Why do I want to do this? I want to be able to show different contents through the url. Is this possible through css?

Example:

```
index.html#test
<div id="test">This is visible</div>
<div id="not">This is not visible</div>
<div id="may">May be visible through a css selector</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:target` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_the_%3atarget_selector).  It's relatively new (CSS3), so [doesn't work in all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t316).

Comment: Awesome Thanks Robert!!! Is anywhere out there a js adding support to older browsers?

Comment: @Manuel  Not that I'm aware of, sorry.  You might be able to roll your own based on a [`hashchange` implementation](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with just CSS. You would need to use JavaScript.